# Error: Invalid JSON RPC response while using INFURA

Tags: javascript, ethereum

getting error:While implementing ethereum blockchain code ,
 error that i am getting is :Invalid JSON RPC response while using INFURA
                                                                  **Attaching error log below kindly help**

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/home/joshi/Desktop/inbox/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/joshi/Desktop/inbox/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:115:32)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/joshi/Desktop/inbox/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/joshi/Desktop/inbox/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (/home/joshi/Desktop/inbox/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:544:12)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/joshi/Desktop/inbox/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:414:24)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't post more information, such as a little piece of code is difficult to understand what is happening.

What you should try is this:

In every link to infura api remove the "/v3" part from the url.

From this:

```
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic,
'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/project_id');
```

To this:

```
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic,
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/project_id');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `www` and `/v3` in infura API URI and it's required to use `https` in the URI. eg.

```
https://rinkeby.infura.io/project_id
```

Comment: By mistake you will use www and say it is not working